# Java's equivalent of arrayof()/ listof()/ setof()/ mapof() from Kotlin

Tags: java, arrays, list, set

I was just wondering that if java has the equivalent of arrayof()/ listof()/ setof()/ mapof() like those in kotlin? If not, is there any way to work similarly? [I found them very different from java.](http://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/index.html)

Btw, do intArrayOf()/ arraylistof()/ hashsetof()/ hashmapof() etc. do the same thing as int[]{}/ new new ArrayList<>()/ new HashSet<>()/ new HashMap<>() etc.?

Comment: `arrayOf()`, `listOf()`, `setOf()` have equivalents (although with more verbose syntax, as usual in Java). However there are simple equivalent for `mapOf()`, at least not as straight-forward as Kotlin's.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Java 9 brings similar methods: [`List#of`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/List.html#of-E...-), [`Set#of`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#of-E...-), [`Map#of`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#of-K-V-K-V-K-V-K-V-K-V-K-V-K-V-K-V-K-V-K-V-) with several overloaded methods to avoid calling the varargs one. In case of `Map`, for varargs, you have to use [`Map#ofEntries`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#ofEntries-java.util.Map.Entry...-).

Pre Java 9, you had to use `Arrays#asList` as entry point to initialize `List` and `Set`:

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("hello", "world");
Set<String> set = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("hello", "world"));
```

And if you wanted your `Set` to be immutable, you had to wrap it inside an immutable set from [`Collections#unmodifiableSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableSet-java.util.Set-):

```
Set<String> set = Collections.unmodifiableSet(
    new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("hello", "world")));
```

For Map, you may use a trick creating an anonymous class that extended a `Map` implementation, and then wrap it inside [`Collections#unmodifiableMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableMap-java.util.Map-). Example:

```
Map<String, String> map = Collections.unmodifiableMap(
    //since it's an anonymous class, it cannot infer the
    //types from the content
    new HashMap<String, String>() {{
        put.("hello", "world");
    }})
    );
```

Comment: Be aware that the double brace initialization syntax is extremely dangerous and can cause memory leaks.

Comment: Great thx but Arrays.asList() returns an ArrayList, does listof() returns an arraylist as well? If so, that would be an duplicate of arraylistof()

Comment: @jerryc05 it returns a class with simple name `ArrayList` but it is not the class `java.util.ArrayList`, instead is a List implementation that doesn’t accept adding or removing elements.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza omg okay I did not realize that lol... I see they extend the same class but they implement different classes. thx

Comment: @jerryc05 they implement the same interface, they do not extend from the same class, that’s more correct